# Capistrano cannot load subversion - capistrano.3.x

Tags: capistrano

This is my first time using capistrano. Lucky or unlucky, capistrano 3 just released. I think I found a bug, maybe not. The capistrano removed svn support. I set scm to svn or subversion, but neither worked. 
Can anyone help me?

cap aborted!
cannot load such file -- capistrano/subversion

Tasks: TOP => production
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 0):

you can use capistrano 2

the svn support had been removed from capistrano 3: http://capistranorb.com/2013/06/01/release-announcement.html